# step function and its integral on real line

Tags: real-analysis, integration

From my course, a step function is defined as:

"Take $[a, b]$ as an interval, define $\phi:[a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that if there is a finite sequence $a=x_0\leq... \leq x_n =$such that$\phi$is a  constant on each open interval $(x_{i−1},x_i)$."

Can a step function be defined on the real line, or is it strictly defined on a closed interval? What about its integral? Is its integral only defined on a closed interval (I am guessing it is, otherwise we are dealing with an improper integral?

My issue arises because in a question I was doing it asks, "define a step function $\phi : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ ". It got me thinking if there is a need in defining a closed interval $[a, b]\in\mathbb{R}$ for a step function to be definable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this definition can easily be extended to the real line.

$\phi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a step function if there is a finite strictly increasing sequence $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ so that $\phi$ is constant on each interval $[x_i, x_{i+1})$ and on the intervals $(- \infty, x_1)$ and $[x_n, \infty)$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function

Comment: Multiple typos? If it's constant over closed intervals, it's constant everywhere... and you say that we have $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ but then proceed to say it's constant on $(-\infty,x_1]$ and $[x_n,\infty)$. What's $n$, and why do we care about those terms specifically? And why is the integral "undefined"? Piecewise continuous functions are Riemann integrable.

Comment: I would suggest you read the properties section in the very wikipedia link in your answer. Unless you're assuming that integrable means $L^1$ or $\infty$ counts as a "constant" that is within the range of $\phi$.

Comment: You're absolutely right.

Comment: Also if you're going to link the wikipedia, I would suggest providing a definition consistent with it.

Comment: I don't see the need, as my definition is consistent with the one OP gave. It obviously cannot be both.

Comment: See my first comment: it still has the issue that this just defines comstant functions, since you are using closed intervals. You've also excluded the non-decreasing property from the sequence $x_n$.

Comment: It should be correct now. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: So if we say that if $(-\infty, x0]$ or $[xn, \infty)$ are not zero then do we say the integral diverges or do we say the integral is not defined?